# SharePoint - Excel Online - Edit in Excel and Edit in Browser multiple users

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am new to SharePoint/SharePoint Online.

I have created a excel document in a document library.
If all users edit via excel online that has no problem.

But If **user1** Edit the excel file in "**Edit in Excel**"(Open in microsoft excel) and other **user2** **Edit in Browser**(Excel Online) then both cant edit file at the same time.

If **user2** tries to edit the file in excel online when **user1** already edited in excel then gets a warning -

**Unfortunately, the workbook needs to be closed on or checked in before you can edit it. If everyone uses Excel Online, you can work on it at the same time.**

I am wondering if there is a way for user1 to edit file in  microsoft Excel and user2 to edit on Excel online at same time.

I tried to find information on this but it says - multiple users can edit only online.
I want to find if there is any other way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Microsoft article regarding co-authoring

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Collaborate-on-Excel-workbooks-at-the-same-time-with-co-authoring-7152aa8b-b791-414c-a3bb-3024e46fb104?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

If you look in the Frequently Asked Questions, the question 'Why can't I see other people's selections?', the answer states that 'only if you and other people are using Excel 2016 for Office 365 subscribers, or Excel Online'.

If I am not mistaken previous version of Excel will by default 'Check-out' the document when opened on the client-side, making it inaccessible until it is checked back in.